# PHP scope question

Tags: php, arrays, scope

I'm trying to look through an array of records (staff members), in this loop, I call a function which returns another array of records (appointments for each staff member).

```
foreach($staffmembers as $staffmember)
{   
        $staffmember['appointments'] = get_staffmember_appointments_for_day($staffmember);
        //  print_r($staffmember['appointments'] works fine 
}
```

This is working OK, however, later on in the script, I need to loop through the records again, this time making use of the appointment arrays, however they are unavailable.

```
foreach ($staffmembers as $staffmember)
{                                                             
        //do some other stuff
        //print_r($staffmember['appointments'] no longer does anything
}
```

Normally, I would perform the function from the first loop, within the second, however this loop is already nested within two others, which would cause the same sql query to be run 168 times.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that the second loop occurs in the same function in which the first loop occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Loops do not have their own scope. At which point are you losing `$staffmembers` and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) iterates over a **copy** of the array. If you want to change the value, you need to [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) it:

```
foreach($staffmembers as &$staffmember) // <-- note the &
{   
    $staffmember['appointments'] = get_staffmember_appointments_for_day($staffmember);
    //  print_r($staffmember['appointments'] works fine 
}
```

From the documentation:

> **Note:** Unless the array is referenced, `foreach` operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. `foreach`  has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the `foreach` without resetting it.

and

> As of PHP 5, you can easily modify array's elements by preceding `$value` with `&`. This will assign [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) instead of copying the value.

Comment: I think that's unrelated to his question. EDIT: ok, I think this is what he meant, not really a scoping issue, really.

Comment: @Artefacto: It is related to scope in a way. The copy is not visible outside the loop ;)

Comment: Well... the *last* copy of `$staffmember` *will* be visible outside the loop, so it's not really a scoping problem... =)